# OpenAL 3D sounds

Tags: audio, openal

In my 3D game I currently have sounds working through a factory class "sound". I am initializing OpenAL through my camera class, on load it will store global floatbuffers of its position, orientation and velocity

```
private static FloatBuffer listenerPosition = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer( 3 ).put( new float[] { X(), Y(), Z() } );
private static FloatBuffer listenerOrientation = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer( 6 ).put (new float[] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f } );
private static FloatBuffer listenerVelocity = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer( 3 ).put (new float[] { Velocity.x, Velocity.y, Velocity.z } );
```

Then on each tick when the camera moves or rotates it updates these with the code

```
listenerVelocity.put(0, Velocity.x);
listenerVelocity.put(1, Velocity.y);
listenerVelocity.put(2, Velocity.z);

alListener( AL_POSITION, listenerPosition );
alListener( AL_ORIENTATION, listenerOrientation );
alListener( AL_VELOCITY, listenerVelocity );
```

This is the class which I think is not enabling OpenAL to know how I want the sound though I am giving it all the information it needs as far as I know.

```
private int ID;

public Sound(String name) {
    try {
        ID = alGenBuffers();
        WaveData data = WaveData.create(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("res/Sound/"+name+".wav")));
        alBufferData(ID, data.format, data.data, data.samplerate);
        data.dispose();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not find \"" + name + "\"", "IO Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void play(float x, float y, float z) {
    playSound(ID, new Vector3f(x,y,z));
}

private static void playSound(int buffer, Vector3f pos) {
    while(alGetSourcei(Sources.get(currentsource), AL10.AL_SOURCE_STATE) == AL_PLAYING) {
        currentsource++;
        currentsource %= 10; //there are only 10 sources
    }
    alSourcei(Sources.get(currentsource), AL_BUFFER,   buffer );
    alSourcef(Sources.get(currentsource), AL_PITCH,    1.0f   );
    alSourcef(Sources.get(currentsource), AL_GAIN,     1.0f   );
    alSourcei(Sources.get(currentsource), AL_LOOPING,  AL_FALSE);
    alSourcef(Sources.get(currentsource), AL_REFERENCE_DISTANCE, 0);
    alSourcef(Sources.get(currentsource), AL_MAX_DISTANCE, 100);

    alSourcePlay(Sources.get(currentsource));
}

public static boolean hasLoaded(){return loaded;}
```

My suspicion is the playSound method, is there a better way of finding a non-playing source? and is there any attributes that I have not given it that would result in sounds not having any 3D attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You should look audio file channels because openAL applies attenuation only to **mono sound**.

Answer (score 0):

Your source position is not set. You might not hear the sound because it is by default at zero position, while your listener is far from there. In playSound try setting something like this:

```
alSourcefv(Sources.get(currentsource), AL_POSITION, sourcePosition);
```

Comment: There is no `alSourcefv` in LWJGL, there are however `alSource(int source, int pname, FloatBuffer value)` and `alSource3f(int source, int pname, float v1, float v2, float v3)`, I tried both, alSource resulted in an internal LWJGL timer error and the second did nothing. I can hear sound just they are always full volume and no matter distance or listeners rotation.